# how do you hide/show divs by offsetting -9999px left?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery script to hide and show divs that contain parts of a form.

Currently the script hides and shows my divs by removing and/or appending them with 'display: none'. I'd like instead to hide/show them by adding/removing 'left: -9999px; position: absolute'.

Is there any way to do this with this script?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tab_pool = ["tab_Chemical", "tab_Crop", "tab_Physical"];
    var visible = $(".tab:visible").attr('class').split(" ")[1];
    var curr_ind = $.inArray(visible, tab_pool);
    $(".submit").hide();
    $(".back").hide();

    var validator = $('form').validate({
        ignore: 'input[type="button"],input[type="submit"]',
        rules: {
            wat_hl: {
                required: true
            },
            zero_height_ref: {
                required : true
            },
            mas_tras_cof: {
                required: true
            }
        }
    });


    $('.next').click(function () {
        var tab = $(".tab:visible");

        var valid = true;
        $('input', tab).each(function(i, v){
            valid = validator.element(v) && valid;
        });

        if(!valid){
            return;
        }

        if (curr_ind < 2) {
            $(".tab:visible").hide();
            curr_ind = curr_ind + 1;
            $("." + tab_pool[curr_ind]).show();
            $(".submit").hide();
            $(".back").show();
        }
        if (curr_ind == 2) {
            $(".submit").show();
            $(".next").hide();
        }
    });

    $('.back').click(function () {
        if (curr_ind > 0) {
            $(".tab:visible").hide();
            curr_ind = curr_ind - 1;
            $("." + tab_pool[curr_ind]).show();
            $(".submit").hide();
            $(".next").show();
        }
        if (curr_ind == 0) {
            $(".back").hide();
        }
    });   
});
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pz9NR/53/).

Answer (score 1):

Replace all instances of `.hide()` (or your display:none) with `.css({position:"absolute",left:"-9999px"})`

and all instances of `.show()` (or your display:block) with `.css({position:"static",left:"auto"})`

This should work unless your divs are positioned absolutely or relatively already.